# Google Sheets HTML view charts not showing

Tags: html, charts, google-sheets, embed

Why are charts in the HTML view of Google Sheets not showing until they are moused over?

The issue has appeared in the past 2 weeks and it's hit all of my published sheets in different places all at once including files I've been using for many years without issues and created with different accounts

You can see on this page the blank boxes and mousing over them will show the charts: https://fevgames.net/ifs-score-sub/. The iframe source is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTuRAapT5_N6X0lsUa_qiguY5BV7hwFY13ZqcMpJBHfEyFzjwCIpw6BzkNbskk3oJkxErJPgib5YvWx/pubhtml?gid=1417662626&single=true&headers=false&widget=false&chrome=false)

I've searched all the things in all the places and still don't have any clue of what could have caused this or if it's a global change to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

SO is not Google's [support forum](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10197028?hl=en).